# Springdata jpa and Native queries

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am doing a spring application and am kind stack. Iam running a query as shown below

```
@Autowired
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

public List countTransactionsGroupByProvider(){
    EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    String query = "SELECT t.order_name,count(t.order_name) as number_of_transactions from transactions_view t where "
            + "t.transaction_date between '2014-07-24' and '2014-10-27' group by t.order_name";
    List result =  em.createNativeQuery(query).getResultList();
    return result;
}
```

Now,This is working fine.it returns the data below:

```
[["Airtel",148], ["Expresso",8], ["Glo",49],
 ["MTN",110],["Select network",1],["Surfline",88],
 ["Tigo",35],["Vodafone",136],["Vouchers",30]]
```

My problem is I want this to return in the below format:

```
[{"order_name":"Airtel","number_of_transactions":148},
 {"order_name":"Expresso","number_of_transactions":8},
 {"order_name":"MTN","number_of_transactions":110},etc]
```

Then I can feed this into morris.js to plot a graph.
Any suggestion as to how to go about this.Thank much

Comment: I don't see anything concerning spring data jpa in this question?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just write some supporting code to transform the data into the format you want. Not sure you're going to get much traction trying to get JPA to produce the data in the format you want although it's arguably not out of the question.